# is there any way to sort firebase arrays by id?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding a new drag and drop feature to my app and I'm trying to find a decent way to implement it. The issue is that I'm dealing with a big array of data, which makes it impractical to send the entire array to the database every time it gets reordered. Is there a native function that can help with this? My current solution is to store the new order in the browser's local storage, but this creates a problem if the user accesses the app from another device. Another solution I'm considering is to create a separate clone array that only contains the item IDs in the new order, which would be stored in Firestore alongside the original array of data. This way, the clone array can serve as a reference on how the original array should be sorted later. Has anyone else faced a similar case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common approaches I know of (each with their own drawbacks) are:

- Allow users to swap items

  So this means that you give every item an index initially to determine their initial order. For example:

  ```
  [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8]
  ```

  Then when the user swaps two items, you swap their indexes behind the scenes. For example if we swap `a` and `c`, it becomes:

  ```
  [c: 1, b: 2, a: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8]
  ```

  If you want to allow the user to drag and drop re-order items, you will have to essentially bubble the item up or down, so change many indexes. Say we do allow that for `a` and `c` again, based on the original data, that be:

  ```
  [b: 1, c: 2, a: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8]
  ```

  At some point this becomes more expensive that loading/saving the entire array, so you'll want to keep an eye out for that.
- Drop items at the mid-way point

  Here again, start by giving each item an initial index, but make sure that index is a floating point number.

  ```
  [a: 1.0, b: 2.0, c: 3.0, d: 4.0, e: 5.0, f: 6.0, g: 7.0, h: 8.0]
  ```

  Now when the user moves an item to a new position, give it an index value that is halfway between the indexes of its new siblings. So if we drag `a` to after `c` again, that'd be:

  ```
  [b: 2.0, c: 3.0, a: 3.5, d: 4.0, e: 5.0, f: 6.0, g: 7.0, h: 8.0]
  ```

  This works *great* as you only have to modify the value for the item you actually moved. But it only works up to a certain number of reorderings, as you will run out of precision bits for your floating point numbers at some point. Imagine we swag `c` and `a` a few times, it'd become:

  ```
  [b: 2.0, a: 3.5, c: 3.75, d: 4.0, e: 5.0, f: 6.0, g: 7.0, h: 8.0]

  [b: 2.0, c: 3.75, a: 3.875, d: 4.0, e: 5.0, f: 6.0, g: 7.0, h: 8.0]

  [b: 2.0, a: 3.875, c: 3.9375, d: 4.0, e: 5.0, f: 6.0, g: 7.0, h: 8.0]
  ```

  I don't recall the exact number of swaps, but I think in JavaScript it can be as low as a couple of dozen in a worst case scenario (swapping the same items over and over) before you run out of precision bits.

  The solution for this problem would then be to re-index all items to whole numbers again occasionally, either periodically or after a certain number of moves.

As said, neither of these is ideal, but they are the two most common approach I know of.